# How to write regex to extract number before some word appears

Tags: regex

E.g. I have strings like below:

1. `1450 AC FR 876 AC - 67 98 AC B3`
2. `1450 AC FR 876 AC Special 67 98 AC B3`

I want to extract number which is before `AC B3`. 
In above example my output value for `AC B3` will be `67 98`

> How to get value?

Before 67 98 can be anything. It may be some words or any special characters but it will not have number.

Comment: `([0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]) AC B3$` would check that there are 2 times 2-digits numbers separated by a space before `AC B3`.

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: Try positive lookahead: `(\d\d\s){2}(?=AC B3)`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 67 98 will always be '## ##' (number number whitespace number number) you could use

`(\d{2}\s\d)\w+`

I always struggle with regex myself, a site I find quite helpful is https://regexr.com/ They have a pretty good cheat sheet to help you figure out the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This will return first occurence of "number-whitespace-number-whitespace-AC-whitespace-B3"

```
result = re.search("\d+\s\d+\sAC\sB3", x)
num1, num2 = result.group().split()[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing which engine/flavor you're using, this is tentative and may have to be adapted:

```
 (\d\d\s){2}(?=AC B3)
```

This works by positive lookahead: "Match the two double-digit numbers if you see `AC B3` on the right"